# How do I get rid of a default input binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded

I have a window with an embedded Chromium view, and a button bound to the `BrowseBack` command.  The button works, but if I press the backspace key, it triggers the BrowseBack command instead of letting the user delete text in a text box inside the Chromium `WebView`.

I thought if I could find the `InputBindingCollection` where the command was bound, I could remove it, but I don't know where the default binding is registered.  I have no idea whether this behavior is a bug in Chromium or expected behavior, or if there is a way to let backspace have the normal effect when a text field is focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use [`ApplicationCommands.NotACommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.notacommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to disable that input binding. This works for the standard WPF controls, and should work for that control as well.
For example:

```
<WebView>
    <WebView.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Backspace" Command="ApplicationCommands.NotACommand"/>
    </WebView.InputBindings>
</WebView>
```

Comment: I had to put it under `<Window.InputBindings>` for it to have effect but it worked!